# Real Analysis - Union of Sets / Intervals

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, solution-verification, supremum-and-infimum

$A:=\{f(x) : x \in [1,2]\} \cup \{x:x\in[1,2]\}$ where $f:[0,4]\to\Bbb R$ given by $f(x):=x^2+2$ for all $x \in [0,4]$.

My working: the range of $f$ is $f([1,2]) = [3,6]$, and $x:x\in[1,2]$ gives $[1,2]$, so $[3,6]\cup[1,2]$.

I know this means that $1\leq x\leq2$ or $3\leq x\leq6$. Does that mean I write $A:=[1,2]\cup[3,6]$? and that is fine to write and fully simplified. Also, out of interest, would the supremum of $A$ be $6$ and infimum be $1$?

Comment: I agree with all your conclusions!

Comment: @GregMartin Thanks mate. I felt silly posting but I wanted to make sure my thinking was correct. Cheers.

Comment: I find your questions far from "silly". For example, you shouldn't write $A\color{red}{:=}[1,2]\cup[3,6]$; you should write $A=[1,2]\cup[3,6]$ since $A$ has already been defined. Supremum of $A$ is $6$ and infimum $1$.

Comment: @StéphaneJaouen Okay I'll change that in my book. Thank you : )